# Grails plugin returning invalid stream header error

Tags: spring, grails, plugins, spring-security

I have a Grails app that uses a plugin I have created. Both use Spring-security-core plugin.

My plugin has a domain class, controller and views. Data to display is selected from a line drawn on a map. The data returned is displayed in a list at the bottom of the browser window. I have created a link on one of the fields that is supposed to show the selected record.

When I click this link, however I get the following error:

```
| Error 2014-05-27 16:14:11,415 [http-bio-8082-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StreamCorruptedException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/bridge/show/661
invalid stream header: 8401FE00. Stacktrace follows:
Message: invalid stream header: 8401FE00
Line | Method
->>  802 | readStreamHeader in java.io.ObjectInputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    299 | <init>           in     ''
|     55 | show . . . . . . in RIMS.bridge.BridgeController
|    195 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

The code that fails is where I attempt to get the data with the ID in the following action:

```
@Secured(["hasRole('ROLE_MAP_USER')"])
def show(Long id) {
    println "ID: ${id}"
    def princObj = springSecurityService?.principal
    log.debug "User: ${princObj}"
    def bridgeInstance = RIMS.bridge.Bridge.get(id)
    if (!bridgeInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'bridge.label', default: 'Bridge'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    render(plugin: "nhvr", view:"show", model: [bridgeInstance: bridgeInstance])
}
```

The returned user, retured at log.debug "User: ${princObj}" is correct and has the required role.

I am not sure how to proceed. Can anyone suggest what to try?

**Here is the code for the Bridge class:**

```
package RIMS.bridge

class Bridge {

        String bridgeNo
        String roadNo
        BigDecimal linkNo
        BigDecimal chng
        String travelDirectionCode
        BigDecimal northing
        BigDecimal easting
        String overUnderCode
        Date dateActive
        Date dateArchived
        String tranUser
        Date tranDateTime
        String tranType
        Serializable obj
        String cwayCode
        String constructed

        static hasMany = [
                          bridgeClearances: BridgeClearance,
                          bridgeCulverts: BridgeCulvert,
                          bridgeDimensions: BridgeDimension,
                          bridgeDrawings: BridgeDrawing,
                          bridgeDucts: BridgeDuct,
                          bridgeHydraulics: BridgeHydraulic,
                          bridgeMaintenances: BridgeMaintenance,
                          bridgeMiscellaneouses: BridgeMiscellaneous,
                          bridgeParts: BridgePart,
                          bridgeServices: BridgeService,
                          bridgeSpans: BridgeSpan,
                          bridgeSubstructures: BridgeSubstructure,
                          bridgeSuperstructures: BridgeSuperstructure]

        static mapping = {      
                    id generator: "assigned"
            version false
        }

        static constraints = {
            bridgeNo maxSize: 10
            roadNo nullable: true, maxSize: 5
            linkNo nullable: true
            chng nullable: true
            travelDirectionCode maxSize: 10
            northing nullable: true
            easting nullable: true
            overUnderCode maxSize: 10
            dateArchived nullable: true
            tranUser maxSize: 30
            tranType maxSize: 6
            obj nullable: true
            cwayCode nullable: true, maxSize: 4
            constructed nullable: true, maxSize: 3
        }

     def locateByBridgeNo(String bridgeNo){
         println "locating by no: ${bridgeNo}"
         withCriteria{
             eq('bridgeNo', bridgeNo)
         }
     }
     static listActiveBridges(){
         withCriteria(){
             isNull('dateArchived')
         }
     }   

     static listBridgesByBridgeNo(String bridgeNo){
         withCriteria(){
             eq('bridgeNo', bridgeNo)
         }
     }

    String toString(){
        return "${bridgeNo} Road: ${roadNo}, Link: ${linkNo}, chainage: ${chng}"
    }    
}
```

Comment: show us your `RIMS.bridge.Bridge` class

Comment: Seems like it is because Hibernate is not included when the plugin is packaged. I can create a service and then connect to the database using the datasource and get the info by running a query..

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error message occurred when I had an `java.time.Instant` as a member field of a class while trying to fetch it from the database with Hibernate 3.6 which did not support serialization of `Instant`.

This is however not a solution to your problem but I add it anyway in case it may be of help to someone who ends up here searching for the same error message.